# Ist "belgischer Bierabend" falsch?

Tags: adjective, compound, adjective-ending

Die Frage hat nichts mit dem Reinheitsgebot zu tun; es geht eher um Grammatik. Ist die folgende Adjektivierung falsch?

> Belgischer Bierabend

Wenn, wie kann man das besser ausdrücken? Natürlich versteht man darunter, dass man an solchem Abend Trappisten und ähnliche kaloriereiche Getränke und so trinkt. Aber da haben wir das Adkejtiv, das eigentlich auf *Abend* wirkt, nicht auf Bier. Daher die Frage.

Comment: Man vergleiche mit der *gebratenen Würstchenbude.*

Comment: Während ich mir eine Bierabend in belgischer Tradition gut vorstellen kann, erscheint mir das Braten einer Würstchenbude doch sehr ungewöhnlich.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Du hast recht, wenn Du schreibst, dass das *belgisch* sich hier grammatikalisch nicht auf *Bier* bezieht. Es bezieht sich aber auch nicht auf *Abend*, sondern auf *Bierabend*. Daher würde ich die Formulierung nicht als falsch empfinden, denn ich würde davon ausgehen, dass man bei einem belgischen Bierabend belgisches Bier trinkt. Wenn Du genauer sein möchtest, musst Du eine andere Formulierung wählen. Wenn also etwa *belgischer Bierabend* falsch wäre, da belgisches Bier auf ganz umbelgische Art getrunken wird, oder wenn tatsächlich Belgier kein einheimisches Bier trinken sollten.

Übrigens wäre *ein Belgisches-Bier-Abend* eindeutig, aber ich würde von dieser Formulierung abraten.

Answer (score 7):

Das zusammengesetzte Nomen müßte getrennt werden:

> Abend des belgischen Biers / Abend mit belgischem Bier

Macht aber kaum jemand. Die grammatisch eigentlich inkorrekte Variante spricht sich eben flüssiger ... (pardon für den Wortwitz).

Comment: Es würde, also, künstlich oder überkorrekt *"Abend des belgischen Biers"*, ne?

Comment: Eventuell könnte man "Belgisches-Bier-Abend" als sehr umgangssprachlichen Ausdruck akzeptieren. So ähnlich wie "in unserer Firma herrscht allgemein eine Der-Nächste-Richtets-Stimmung."